# Excerpt for sub-pages

Tags: wordpress

I have this code that displaying my sub pages with their thumbnails and titles.
I added another line that show the excerpt too, but some reason when I'm click on 'view more'  it doesn't link to the page. 
this is the code I  used:

```
     <?php
    //list of all sub pages with thumbmails//
    $child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID." AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT'); ?>
      <?php if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>
      <li>
        <div class="child-thumb">
        <div class="child-thumbFrame"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID) ) { echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'planesThumb'); }
else {
    echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/thumbnail-default.jpg" />';}?></div>
        <div class="child-thumb-titels">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?> </a>
        <div class="child-thumb-excerpt"><?php $customLength=20; echo get_the_excerpt($post->ID); ?></div>

         </div></li>

      <?php endforeach; endif;?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no view more in given code
And following code will do the required job

```
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = 13 ", 'OBJECT');

?>
<?php if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>
  <li>
    <div class="child-thumb">
    <div class="child-thumbFrame">
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID) ) 
  { echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'planesThumb'); }
    else { echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/thumbnail-default.jpg" />';}?>
    </div>
    <div class="child-thumb-titels">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?> </a>
    <div class="child-thumb-excerpt">
        <?php $customLength=20; echo get_the_excerpt($post->ID); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>">View more</a>
    </div>

     </div></li>

  <?php endforeach; endif;?>
```

Place this code inside the query loop, there is nothing wrong with your code.